# CSS - target the first element with class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

HTML:

```
<p class=menu_top>Title</p>
<p class=menu_top>Order</p>
<p class=menu_top>Position</p>
<p class=menu_top>Number</p>
```

How can I target just the first element?

Comment: In what browser? What are your requirements? What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) pseudo-class.

```
.menu_top:first-child {
    your: rules;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uKJcK/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just as a point of note, the way you're structuring is going to cause you more work in the future, as well. It would be far better to have something like this:

```
<div class="menu_top">
    <p>Title</p>
    <p>Order</p>
    <p>Position</p>
    <p>Number</p>
</div>
```

(and more semantically-correct would be to make it an unordered list) 
The repetition is not necessary, when you can simply spec in CSS like so:

```
.menu_top p {
    //all my basic styles for each menu item
}

.menu_top p:first-child {
    // specific styles for just the first menu item
}
```

Over-classing causes a load of rework in the future, and muddies the code. Use the cascade to your advantage; it cuts down on repetitive code, and makes it easier to override only the outliers.